# Magento 2 Observer class print event data

Tags: magento2, php, event-observer

I want to preview all the details inside the object such as Order, Customers after saving the event. I tired below way but it not printing the object inside attributes....

Customer Object `Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer`

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
$var_dump($order);

and

$customer= $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$var_dump($customer);

also 

print_r($customer->debug());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
print_r($order->getData()); 
// or specific variable name like
print_r($order->getOrderId()); 
and

$customer= $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
print_r($customer->getId());
print_r($customer->getName());
print_r($customer->getEmail());
```